# Reliability of Mimetypes in Uploads (PHP)

Tags: php, security, file-upload, mime-types, mime

I've had this question for a while: how exactly is the mime type of a file determined? I believe this is done by checking if specific bytes of the file contain any of the known [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) / [file signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), right?

If so, this poses another question, lets say I upload a bash script with a fake GIF file signature to a website that only allows images to be uploaded, what is going to happen? Either:

1. the mimetype detection routine is smart enough to detect fake signatures, or
2. `image/gif` is wrongly returned as the mimetype and the upload is allowed to continue

I don't have an HEX editor installed ATM, and I don't like to form security-related conclusions from tests as I might miss (or misinterpret) something, so my question is: which one of the above options is correct?

Also, are there any other best practices (besides checking the mimetype) to assure that any given file is in fact what it seems / needs (or is allowed) to be? Thanks in advance.

**PS:** Just to be clear, I'm not asking about the `type` index in the `$_FILES` superglobal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is the MIME determination routines in the file upload code are extremely crude and that the MIME type in the $_FILES array simply can't be trusted.  It's been my experience that it's easily foxed.

You're better off using the Fileinfo library, which provides more robust file type detection.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Comment: The `type` index in `$_FILES` comes from the browser / user, it can't be trusted at all. I'm using Fileinfo (or similars), but the question still applies: If the mime is faked, is Fileinfo smart enough to detect that?

Comment: As far as what I understand from the documentation, Fileinfo looks at the header plus does some heuristics to detect filetype and does not require (or rely on) information sent by the browser.

Comment: The page on fileinfo in the PHP manual says the file detection isn't 100% reliable.  I would assume you could craft a file that can fool it.

Comment: @GordonM: Do you know of any method that is more reliable than Fileinfo?

Comment: I suppose you could exec() an external utility such as *ix file.  I think the file utility works the same way that fileinfo does though, by looking for magic bytes in files.  My suspicion is there's no 100% reliable way of determining file types.  After all, you can append a PHP script onto a GIF file and it would still look like a GIF file to image viewers.  Rather than trying to find a way to guarantee the file type, you're probably better off finding a way of sandboxing uploaded files and limiting what they can do, such as turning the PHP engine off for the directory they're uploaded into

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` then this information is sent by the browser. It may or may not be present and even if its present you should treat it just like any other user input.

If you're interested in checking for images you can use the getimagesize function to determine file type. This function returns NULL for images it cannot understand. Even if it returns a valid image type you can still reject the file e.g. if you're expecting GIF and JPEGs and you get a TIFF instead.

Also, a webserver will determine whether to execute a file of not depending on file permissions (the execute bit and the shebang line) and file extension. If you keep a check on these two you're probably OK.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that this (vulnerable MIME types) is the reason that filename's should be encrypted through various means when they're uploaded and then stored in a database to be retrieved via ID numbers. Basically should someone manage to upload a malicious script, they'll never be able to find it to run it?

Comment: But storing on a database or CDN is not always an option. Obscuring the filename can't be considered secure, and has the effect of losing possibly valuable semantic data (the filename itself). I'm aware of the architectural options and precautions, but my question is mainly oriented towards mime type (wrong?) detection and possible alternatives.