# Upload form: can upload plain text .txt document but not .docx or PDF...?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

Thanks for this opportunity to ask. I have extensively searched for the answer but I couldn't find it. I hope that you guys can provide some insight as to why this problem is occurring.

The puzzle: I've set up a form to upload documents so that my website's visitors can submit articles for review. The form used to work properly for all file extensions that were specified, docx, .txt, PDF, etc. However, suddenly, the form displayed an error message if one tried to upload any other format except .txt (strangely, these work fine). I checked with the Host providers and nothing is being recorded in the error logs.

The following is the relevant code in question:

```
function saveUploadedFile() {
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "txt", "doc", "docx", "dot");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["cFile"]["name"]));

if (   (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
        || ($_FILES["cFile"]["type"] == "application/plain")
        || ($_FILES["cFile"]["type"] == "text/plain")
        || ($_FILES["cFile"]["type"] == "application/msword"))
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

    if ($_FILES["cFile"]["error"] > 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        $fileName = $_FILES["cFile"]["name"];
        return $fileName;
    }
}

return '';
}

// Write for us form
    else if (isset($_FILES['cFile']['name'])) {
        if ((isset($_POST['cName']) && !empty($_POST['cName']))
                && (isset($_POST['cEmail']) && !empty($_POST['cEmail']) &&     isValidEmail($_POST['cEmail']))
                && (isset($_POST['cMessage']) && !empty($_POST['cMessage']))
                && !empty($_FILES['cFile']['name'])) {

            $cName = $_POST['cName'];
            $cEmail = $_POST['cEmail'];
            $cMessage = $_POST['cMessage'];
            $fileName = saveUploadedFile();

            if ($fileName != '') {
                $to = 'contact@REMOVED.com';
                $subject = 'Article';
                $msg = 'Author: ' . $cName . "\n" . 'Message: ' . $cMessage;


                $fileSize = $_FILES['cFile']['size'];
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['cFile']['tmp_name'], 'r');
                $content = fread($handle, $fileSize);
                fclose($handle);

                $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
                $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

                $headers = "From: " . $cName . " <" . $cEmail . ">
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\" 

This is a multi-part message in MIME format. 
--" . $uid . "
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $fileName . "\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $fileName . "\"

" . $content . "

--" . $uid . "
Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 
" . $msg . "
--" . $uid . "--";

                if (!@mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
                    echo '<p class="failed validation">The e-mail could not be sent.     Please try again later</p>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p class="success validation">Your message has been sent</p>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<p class="failed validation">Your file could not be uploaded.  Please make sure that you attached one of the following types of files: a plain text file, a MS Word document, a PDF file or a zip file</p>';
            }
        } else {
             echo '<p class="failed validation">Your file could not be uploaded.  Please make sure you have completed all required fields and that you have provided a valid email address.</p>';
        }
    }
```

This is the error message that appears: "Your file could not be uploaded. Please make sure that you attached one of the following types of files: a plain text file, a MS Word document, a PDF file or a zip file"

Why will this code accept .txt files but not .docx or PDF?

Thank you!

Comment: You should echo `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` and look whats inside that variable during a failed upload.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this since the website is already live..

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that ["type"] does not work that well. I suggest remove that part of the code.

Comment: Hi Ani, do you mean that I should just remove the parts where it states '["type"] or alter the code any further?

Comment: Remove the type check thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your code as follows:

```
if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["cFile"]["error"] > 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        $fileName = $_FILES["cFile"]["name"];
        return $fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done the tests on the live; the code runs fine and it recognizes the data type but when it comes to this part '($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")' it shows as false when compared with a PDF (and therefore showing an error msg). There seems to be a inconsistency with the standards or something? Please help! Thank u!

Comment: As already mentioned by Ani `$_FILES['file']['type']` isn't a very reliable way to recognize filetypes. In this case I guess your test-pdf returns a slightly different filetype. You could `echo` the filetype of the uploaded pdf to see what you get for your pdf.

Comment: Hi oktopus, as instructed I used the following code to echo the file types: if($cEmail=="me@whoever.com"){
echo " type: ".$_FILES["cFile"]["type"];
echo " ext: ".$extension;

if ($_FILES["cfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf") {
echo " this is a pdf";
} else{
echo " not a pdf";
}
} the output that I get is: type: application/pdf ext: pdf, not a pdf - I'm just unsure how I can change the code so it doesn't employ the unreliable use of $_FILES["cFile"]["type"].

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right. But if you use the code provided by me I thought there is no `type` anymore?!?
Can you add your currently used code in your question?

Comment: Checking for the extension WILL TELL YOU **NOTHING**. You should check for the mime type instead. Even check for the $_FILES type would be better - but still it is not reliable - ready this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000229/reliability-of-mimetypes-in-uploads-php